# Functorizing a choice of sections

Tags: category-theory

Take $\mathcal{C}$ and $T$ to be categories (if it helps, assume $T$ is a poset with a minimal element and $\mathcal{C}$ is cartesian closed). Take a functor $P\colon T\to \mathcal{C}$ where the image of every arrow is a split epimorphism in $\mathcal{C}$.

> Mini question: is there an established name for a functor like that?

Let $S$ be a particular choice of section for each arrow (that is, for every arrow $t$ in $T$, choose an arrow $St$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $Pt\circ St=\mathrm{id}$). Clearly $St'\circ St$ is a section of $P(t\circ t')$, but it need not be the case that $St'\circ St=S(t\circ t')$; in other words, $S$ need not be a functor from $T^{\mathrm{op}}$ to $\mathcal{C}$. I'm looking for a way to "functorize" this choice. That is,

> Question: is there a way, given $P$ and $S$, as above, to produce a functor $S^*\colon T^{op}\to \mathcal{C}$ where for every arrow $t$ in $T$, $Pt\circ S^*t = \mathrm{id}$?

---

I've tried googling for the mini question, but I just kept finding the basic definitions of preserving/reflecting/creating limits which don't quite seem to fit the bill. As for the "big" question, I've made some attempts at building $S^*$ from compositions of images of $P$ and $S$, but I always end up with a composition going the wrong way ($S_t\circ P_t$ instead of $P_t\circ S_t$). It might be possible to conjure them up as limits/colimits of some diagram (probably having to add some requirements on $P$ to make sure they exist), but I'm not quite sure how.

The motivating context is seeing $T$ as a reversed representation of time (with the minimal element of $T$ representing $\infty$), and $P$ as a dynamic process, where information about some unknown underlying state is accumulated over time. In this view, $Pt$ can be seen as "forgetting" the information obtained during a time interval $t$, and $St$ as "guessing" what the information will be after that interval, based on what has been observed so far (and also as assuring that the process can never get stuck). $S^*$ would then be a "consistent" guessing, in the sense that if I make a guess about some point in the future, and the observations halfway to that point are consistent with that guess, then my guess doesn't change.

A more technical motivation is that I'm trying to make the category that has these functors as objects and natural transformations as arrows cartesian closed (assuming that $\mathcal{C}$ is). I know of similar results for categories of arbitrary functors, either with additional restrictions on the target category or by obtaining only local cartesian closure; the ones that aren't way above my level of knowledge don't seem to apply in this case.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that a functorial choice of splitting always exists.

Comment: @zhenlin In general that's probably true. I'm ok with adding some restrictions on the stuff involved to ensure it exists, but I was hoping to get away without too many. In particular, requiring every $Pt$ to be an isomorphism would be too restrictive for my setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want there to exist *at least one $S$* for every possible $P$, you will need very restrictive hypotheses. For example, you might require $\mathcal T$ to be the free category on some graph. This includes the case where $\mathcal T$ is the poset of natural numbers, but not the nonnegative positive reals.

I think the correct thing to say is that

> functors $P: \mathcal T \to \mathcal C$ such that for every morphism $t$ of $T$, $Pt$ is a split epimorphism

is simply the wrong collection of objects to be considering. Instead, you might consider

> Pairs $(P,S)$ where $P: \mathcal T \to \mathcal C$ and $S: \mathcal T ^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal C$ are functors such that for every arrow $t$ of $T$, $Pt \circ St = 1$

Then if $(P,S)$ is one of these objects, it is indeed the case that for every arrow $t$ of $T$, $Pt$ is a split epi, but more is true.

You can make this collection of objects into a category in a very reasonable way by saying that a morphism $(P,S) \to (P',S')$ is a collection of arrows $(\alpha_T)_{T \in \operatorname{Ob} \mathcal T}$ which is simultaneously a natural transformation $P \implies P'$ and a natural transformation $S \implies S'$; and define composition in the obvious way.

This category admits another description: it is the category of functors from $\mathcal T'$ to $\mathcal C$, where $\mathcal T'$ is the category obtained from $\mathcal T$ by freely adjoining a section $s_t$ to every morphism $t$ of $\mathcal T$ and requiring that $s_t \circ s_{t'} = s_{t' \circ t}$. As a functor category, it will inherit lots of nice properties from $\mathcal C$.

Comment: I think $\mathcal{T}'$ is supposed to be the category obtained from $\mathcal{T}$ by freely adjoining a section for every morphism in $\mathcal{T}$ _subject to the constraint that the sections compose_.

Comment: Good point. I'll fix that.

Comment: Actually, restricting $T$ like that might just be the ticket; I'll try pursuing that further :3

Comment: (I deleted my previous comments as they were actually irrelevant).
The reason I'm not keen on $\alpha$ having to be natural $S\Rightarrow S'$ is because a lot of the systems I'm trying to capture just won't have that property. What I'm trying to express is some notion of causality, by saying that the action of the system (the components of $\alpha$) commutes with "trimming down" the given information up to some point in the past (the arrows of $P$ and $P'$).

Comment: The additional restriction would mean that, in a sense, $\alpha$ is not allowed to "add information of its own" to its output, which I most likely want to allow (for example, a system that ignores its input and emits a constant signal should be permissible, regardless of what the output's designated guess says).
In the end though, I just dropped the invertibility requirement on $P$ altogether and moved to work on the whole of $\mathcal{C}^T$, just adding the additional requirements as premises when I need them for a specific construction.